# Rails 3 application : RoutingError like : /stripe/hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am not understanding from where I am getting these requests.
below I have pasted the error log, please have a look :

```
Started POST "/stripe/hook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-12 12:20:33 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/stripe/hook"):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@aq/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)


Started POST "/callbacks/geo/berkeley/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-12 12:20:34 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/callbacks/geo/berkeley"):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@aq/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)


Started POST "/callbacks/geo/berkeley/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-12 12:20:34 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/callbacks/geo/berkeley"):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@aq/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)


Started POST "/upload/pandastatus" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-12 12:20:38 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/upload/pandastatus"):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@aq/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)


Started POST "/upload/pandastatus" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-12 12:20:40 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/upload/pandastatus"):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@aq/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)


Started POST "/upload/pandastatus" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-12 12:20:45 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/upload/pandastatus"):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is scanning the localtunnel subdomains for open hooks. These request are coming from `localtunel connection` with [localtunel service](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a necessary method in your controller related to your upload -- that is, some sort of `create` or `upload` method. Be sure to run `rake routes` as well.

Comment: friend I want to know from where I am getting these requests.

Comment: @rkp, I don't understand your comment.